# How can I remotely debug a C# .NET 4.5 WinForms application on a Raspberry Pi 3 using Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mono, remote-debugging, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I am attempting to remotely debug a C# .NET 4.5 WinForms application on a Raspberry Pi 3 (running Raspbian Jessie) using Visual Studio 2015 on a Windows machine.

As I understand it, I can use [MonoRemoteDebugger](https://github.com/techl/MonoRemoteDebugger) for this. I've installed the Visual Studio extension and run the server program on the Pi but when I attempt to debug the application the MonoRemoteDebugger.Server.exe program displays an error which comes from the pdb2mdb.exe program. Here is the error:

> Fatal error: Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbDebugException: Unknown custom
>   metadata item kind: 6   at
>   Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbFunction.ReadCustomMetadata
>   (Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.BitAccess bits) [0x00000] in :0
>   at Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbFunction..ctor (System.String module,
>   ManProcSym proc, Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.BitAccess bits) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbFunction.LoadManagedFunctions (System.String
>   module, Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.BitAccess bits, UInt32 limit, Boolean
>   readStrings) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbFile.LoadFuncsFromDbiModule
>   (Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.BitAccess bits, Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.DbiModuleInfo
>   info, Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.IntHashTable names,
>   System.Collections.ArrayList funcList, Boolean readStrings,
>   Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.MsfDirectory dir,
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 nameIndex,
>   Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbReader reader) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbFile.LoadFunctions (System.IO.Stream read,
>   Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.BitAccess bits, Boolean readAllStrings) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbFile.LoadFunctions
>   (System.IO.Stream read, Boolean readAllStrings) [0x00000] in :0    at Pdb2Mdb.Driver.Convert (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition
>   assembly, System.IO.Stream pdb,
>   Mono.CompilerServices.SymbolWriter.MonoSymbolWriter mdb) [0x00000] in
>   :0

I've tried running the command "pdb2mdb MyProgram.exe" on the Pi and it produces the same error so it appears that the issue is with the pdb2mdb.exe program. With some digging I found that it appears that this was a bug in Mono.Cecil which [was fixed](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/issues/186) in version 0.9.6 but it seems like the latest version available for Raspian Jessie is 0.9.5.

I've tried just replacing pdb2mdb.exe with [the one from here](https://gist.github.com/jbevain/ba23149da8369e4a966f) and the error then changes to:

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition' from assembly 'pdb2mdb,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. [ERROR] FATAL
>   UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition' from assembly 'pdb2mdb,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Is the solution to try to get a newer Mono.Cecil version on the Pi? If so, how would I go about that, as well as ensure that pdb2mdb.exe references the newer version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved the problem!

The first issue was with pdb2mdb.exe. The wheezy package source from mono-project.com had to be used to get the latest mono packages using these commands:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mono-complete mono-devel
```

After that, MonoRemoteDebugger in Visual Studio was displaying the following error:

> Unable to start program 'C:\Test1\Test1.exe'.
>
> The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference.

To work around this I removed the MonoRemoteDebugger 1.0.5 Visual Studio extension and installed [version 1.0.4](https://github.com/techl/MonoRemoteDebugger/releases) which doesn't have this problem.